# PHP cURL post fields from user input

Tags: php, forms, elasticsearch, curl

My problem is the following I have a HTML web form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>FORM</title>
<body>

<form action="/form/send/alex.php" method="post" >

Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="email"><br>
<input type="submit">



</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And I want to ingest/ship the user input  into Elasticsearch with php curl, but this is not working :( and I do not know how to do this form the web form. If I change the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // input fileds` with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "\n{\n  \"@timestamp\": \"2021-11-29T08:21:15.000Z\",\n  \"message\": \"monday\"\n}\n");` is working but this hard-code and I want to insert the user input.

Now this is the back-end conde:

```
<?php

// THIS ARRAY CONTAINS THE INPUT FIELDS DATA
$data = array(
    "name" => "",
    "email" => ""
);




// START THE CURL PROCESS
$ch = curl_init(); // initialize


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ip/index/_doc?pretty'); // form location url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // form method
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // input fileds

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The error I receive is 504 Gateway Time-out

Thank you for your time and help,
Alex

Comment: Can you try once with full URL in `CURLOPT_URL` ?

Comment: I did put the full url there, is working, but only with hardcoded input :(

Comment: You are using `ip/index/_doc?pretty` this url so i am saying can you try once with full URL like `http://example.com/ip/index/_doc?pretty` like this. Just replace `example.com` with your host name like `localhost` or something else. Because CURL cant detect automatically so you should try once.

Comment: In your "working" version, you are sending JSON. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);` - here $data won't magically turn into JSON by itself.

Comment: @CBroe  the working version is this : ```<?php
$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ip:port/remote/_doc?pretty');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "\n{\n  \"@timestamp\": \"2021-11-29T08:21:15.000Z\",\n  \"message\": \"monday\"\n}\n");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);```

Comment: in the working curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, i have the input from my self, and in the not working one is "user input"  $data from the beginning array

Comment: @Sateesh still 504 :(

Comment: What data does this API expect from you? In your working version, you send a JSON containing properties `@timestamp` and `message`, and the data you are trying to send now, has `name` and `email` instead. Is it supposed to accept the latter?

Comment: So my expectation is to send user input ( name e-mail does not matter) into elasticsearch. Now I have a working version of this php script that i send @timestamp and message but this does not mattr because there it could be name or e-mail.

Capturing the user input and sending is the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

If you will use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ip/index/_doc?pretty');` then it will throw an error `Error: Could not resolve host: ip` because it assuming that host name is `ip/` so you should use `HOST/URL` like `http://yourhost.com/ip/index/_doc?pretty`. You can look into the code i have just replace URL with `google.com` and it's working fine because host is reachable now.

```
<?php

// THIS ARRAY CONTAINS THE INPUT FIELDS DATA
$data = array(
    "name" => "",
    "email" => ""
);

// START THE CURL PROCESS
$ch = curl_init(); // initialize


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://google.com'); // form location url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // form method
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // input fileds

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo 'Form submitted successfully';
}

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Hey @Sateesh, thx for answer but  the term "ip" in the  ```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ip/index/_doc?pretty');``` is not the the name of my dns, i just changed the real host with "ip", i do not wanted to share the destination publicly.

Comment: Okay got it. If solution worked then please like. Thanks